# Cannot import name array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib, ubuntu-16.04

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "/home/zaverichintan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from matplotlib.externals.six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/home/zaverichintan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/externals/six.py", line 90, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "/home/zaverichintan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/externals/six.py", line 158, in _resolve
    module = _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/zaverichintan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/externals/six.py", line 80, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/zaverichintan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/home/zaverichintan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 69, in <module>
    from array import array
ImportError: cannot import name array
```

I have imported numpy , scipy , matplotlib and opencv.
The code getting executed on windows 7 machine but after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04, getting error like this.
the python version shows 2.7 but on the ubuntu site it is showing python 3.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First off could you specify which python version are you trying to run and which one was your `try5.py` written for? Python2 and python3 are not the same.

Comment: try5.py is written and tested in python 2.7.

Comment: So what do you mean with 'ubuntu site is showing python 3'? Could you check version of python env you are running script against?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers says python 3.5 is shipped.But when I run python --version it shows Python 2.7.12 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

Comment: It looks like you have a file in your working directory called `array.py`, which your code is trying to import, rather than the stock python module `array`. If you do have such a file, try renaming it or moving it somewhere else

Comment: Array.py was lying as one of the file in the list independent of this file. But somehow it was showing this error . Thanks Tom.